# SQL GROUP BY alias

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2016

I have a smallint column which is used to represent a time. I've written the below code to derive a result depending on what the time is:

```
        CASE
    WHEN 
        CONVERT(varchar, t0.U_ORC_BE_ProdTime, 108) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '19:00:00' THEN '1'
    ELSE '2'
END  AS [Shift],
    --If time is between 7am and 7pm then Shift 1, else Shift 2
```

I want to insert it into a query I already have and then have it also group by the shift.

```
    SELECT 

T6.U_ORC_BE_StyleName AS [Style Name],
T0.[ItemCode],
STUFF(T0.[ItemCode], 1, 6, '') AS [Shortened ItemCode],
SUM(T0.[PlannedQty]) AS [Planned Qty],
SUM(T0.CmpltQty) AS [Actual Qty], 
SUM(T0.CmpltQty) - SUM(T0.PlannedQty) AS [Qty Difference],
SUM(T5.U_ORC_BE_HECTOLITER * T0.CmpltQty) AS [Total Hectoliters],

CASE
    WHEN [.......]
    THEN
    WHEN [.......]
    THEN
END AS [Line],

T0.U_ORC_BE_ProdDate AS [Date Produced]

    FROM [.......]

    GROUP BY T6.U_ORC_BE_StyleName, T0.[ItemCode], T5.Code , T0.U_ORC_BE_ProdDate
```

It keeps throwing up an error though which I suspect is due to attempting to group by the alias name.

"Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: What is the error that is thrown?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question to include the error.

Comment: Where is `T0.U_ORC_BE_ProdDate`  in select , if you are not selecting it then removed from `Group by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To group by a calculated column like a case statement, you have to include that statement in the group by also.  For example:

```
SELECT
  CASE ... END AS CaseStatement,
  [YourColumns]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CASE ... END
```

Comment: Seems so obvious! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As described by the error, you cannot group by the alias name. You would have to replicate the entire case when after your group by.

```
 select 
 ....
 group by 
 T6.U_ORC_BE_StyleName, T0.[ItemCode], T5.Code , T0.U_ORC_BE_ProdDate,
 CASE
    WHEN [.......]
    THEN
    WHEN [.......]
    THEN
END
```

Comment: When given to me like this it makes much more sense. Thank you for your help.